# Understanding Swift + NSError - All paths through this function will call itself

Tags: swift, nserror

After working with `Objective-C` for a long time I have just started to work with `Swift` as well.

I know that `Swift` uses the `Error` protocol instead of `NSError` and in future I will use custom `Error` implementations as well. However, currently I need to work with `NSError` in `Swift` and I found the following code to easily access `NSError` properties on `Error`:

```
extension Error {
    var code: Int { return (self as NSError).code }
    var userInfo: [AnyHashable? : Any?] { return (self as NSError).userInfo }
}
```

While I found an example for the `code` part in an answer here, I added the `userInfo` part myself. It is now problem to access `someError.code` using this extension. However, when using `someError.userInfo` the app chrashes after calling the getting over and over again.

Xcode shows a warning which explains the source of the problem:

> All paths through this function will call itself

Why is this?

As far as I know `Error` is just a protocol which can be implemented by any class. `Error` it self does not have `code` or `userInfo` properties, so `(self as NSError).userInfo should not call`Error.userInfo`, should it?

So I do not understand why this is a problem. Additionally I do not understand why this is a problem for `userInfo` but not for `code`...

Any idea what's the reason for this?

Comment: `var userInfo: [String: Any] { return (self as NSError).userInfo }` or `var nsUserInfo: [String: Any] { return (self as NSError).userInfo }`

Comment: If you want to work with `NSError`, why don't you use `NSError` instead of `Error`? Or why don't you declare your own `Error` implementation? Extending protocol `Error` is not a good idea.

Comment: @Sulthan Because `Objective-C` methods which use/return `NSError` are automatically bridged to use `Error` in `Swift`. I cannot change this to be `NSError`, can I?  @Rob thanks, this will work. However the question is why it does not work in the first place. Why is accessing the `userInfo` a problem and accessing `code` is not?